# Combine MySQL Queries in PHP

Tags: mysql

**I have the following MySQL queries:**

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT imgURL, imgTitle, FROM images
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT imgFamily FROM images
```

**Query #3:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT imgClass FROM images
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to combine them into **one** query? In other words, `SELECT imgURL, imgTitle, DISTINCT imgFamily, and DISTINCT imgClass`.

When I attempted to do it as above (without the `and`), it failed. Any suggestions?

---

The result I get is the following: `MySql ErrorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT imgFamily FROM images`

The result I expect is to not have an error, and have rows returned.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "failed"?

Comment: Post the results you get and the results you expect?

Comment: @Abe Miessler I got no results is what I mean. Why? Should they combine fine?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is per result row, not per individual result field. Are you trying to return the entire list of images along with the entire list of imgFamilies and entire list of imgClasses? That doesn't make sense, as they are different pieces of information and must thus be separate queries.

Comment: @Wiseguy Thanks very much. That makes sense. I'm still working to understand PHP. But that totally makes sense, and I feel like an idiot. I'll keep them separate.

Comment: To fix the syntax error, you'd have to remove all `DISTINCT` keywords except for one immediately after `SELECT` (optional, obviously). However, as explained above, I don't think those results would yield what you're actually looking for.

Comment: If you were to do `SELECT imgURL, imgTitle, imgFamily, imgClass ...`, that would give you the family and class that each particular image is in. If 30 of the images had the same family, then those 30 result rows would all have the same value in family. I don't think that's what you want, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` keyword in MySQL is a synonym for `distinctrow` - eg. If you want a 'select distinct'. you're going to get only the rows where the combination of fields has not yet appeared in the results. By selecting non-distinct fields, you won't get ANY distinct results. This has to be done as separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them with the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) keyword:

```
SELECT imgURL, imgTitle, FROM images
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT imgFamily, NULL FROM images
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT imgClass, NULL FROM images
```

but it's a really bad idea. All columns in subsequent queries must have the same type as columns from all subsequent queries, or some data may get truncated.

Generally, you shouldn't combine unrelated queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct imgURL, imgTitle, imgFamily, imgClass 
FROM images
```

The above will give you unique row.

```
SELECT imgURL, imgTitle, imgFamily, imgClass 
FROM images
```

This one will give you all data.

it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do.